# numpy assert_equals for nested floating point

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, equality

I got a strange behaviour regarding an equal check for the weights for the vgg16 machine learning model

loading two times the model

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torchvision.models import vgg16
import numpy as np
import torchvision.models as models

model = models.vgg16(weights='IMAGENET1K_V1')
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'vgg16_model.pth')

vgg = vgg16(pretrained=True)
vgg.load_state_dict(torch.load("vgg16_model.pth", map_location='cpu'), strict=True)
params1 = np.array([param.detach().numpy() for param in vgg.parameters()], dtype=object)

vgg2 = vgg16(pretrained=True)
vgg2.load_state_dict(torch.load("vgg16_model.pth", map_location='cpu'), strict=True)
params2 = np.array([param.detach().numpy() for param in vgg2.parameters()], dtype=object)
```

note that I didn't replace any layer, if I do the check with `np.assert_equals`

```
np.array_equal(params1, params2)
```

I got `False`

But if I check the nested arrays iteratively the arrays are equals:

```
for val1, val2 in zip(params1, params2):
    print(np.array_equal(val1, val2))
```

What am I missing? Is it due to the way of how I create the array at the start, as `dtype=object`?

```
python version 3.9.13
numpy version 1.21.5
```

Comment: What does `params1==params2` produce?  Any warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the `object` type seems to be the problem – note that you can even simplify your example as follows (tested with Numpy 1.24.3 on Python 3.10.10):

```py
vgg = vgg16(pretrained=True)
vgg.load_state_dict(torch.load("vgg16_model.pth", map_location='cpu'), strict=True)
params_list = [param.detach().numpy() for param in vgg.parameters()]
params1 = np.array(params_list, dtype=object)
params2 = np.array(params_list, dtype=object)
print(np.array_equal(params1, params2))
# >>> False
```

That is, even if the elements inside your `params1` and `params2` object arrays are *identical* float arrays (not only *equal/equivalent* ones), the comparison will return `False`.

The comparison of Numpy arrays of type `object` to me seems rather unintuitive and is not very well documented. The only documentation hinting at this behavior that I could find is in some old [Numpy release notes](https://numpy.org/doc/1.19/release/1.9.0-notes.html#object-array-equality-comparisons):

> ###### Object array equality comparisons
>
> In the future object array comparisons both *==* and *np.equal* will not make use of identity checks anymore. For example:
>
> ```py
> >>> a = np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), 1])
> >>> b = np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), 1])
> >>> a == b
> ```
>
> will consistently return False (and in the future an error) even if the array in *a* and *b* was the same object.

While your observed behavior is described there, the decision as to *why* this comparison returns `False` is not really motivated.

*Bottom line:* If you want to have element-wise comparisons of Numpy arrays, maybe don't use the `object` type. For further reading, maybe also have a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52715049/).

Answer (score 0):

In 1.24

```
In [83]: >>> a = np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), 1],object)
    ...: >>> b = np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), 1],object)

In [84]: a==b
<ipython-input-84-a6f7ccb4d5ba>:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  a==b
Out[84]: False
```